# If one side of $\int f\ d\lambda = \int f\ d\mu - \int f\ d\nu$ exists, does the other one exist as well?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two positive measures, at least one of which is finite, on a measurable space $(X, \mathfrak{A})$. Let $\lambda$ be a signed measure on $(X, \mathfrak{A})$ defined by setting $\lambda = \mu - \nu$. Let $f$ be an extended real-valued $\mathfrak{A}$-measurable function on $X$.

If $f$ is bounded, it can be shown that
$$
\int_X f\ d\lambda = \int_X f\ d\mu - \int_X f\ d\nu \tag{*}
$$
in the sense that both sides of the equation exist in $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ and are equal.

Moreover, if $f$ is unbounded and *both* sides of $(*)$ exist, it can be shown that the equality holds.

Suppose $f$ is unbounded. Is it possible for only one side of $(*)$ to exist, but not the other? It may be assumed that $f$ is non-negative.

---

[The following theorem from Yeh's "Real Analysis", 2nd edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjmIC.jpg), claims that the existence of one side implies that of the other one. However, in my opinion, the proof does not prove this; it only proves the two cases mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the measurable space $\left(\left(0,\infty\right),\mathcal{B}\right)$,
where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu$ be
the usual Lebesgue measure on this space.

Let $M_{n}:=\left(n,n+2^{-n}\right)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note
that the sets $\left(M_{n}\right)_{n}$ are pairwise disjoint with
$\sum_{n}\mu\left(M_{n}\right)<\infty$. Thus, the measure $\nu$
defined by
$$
d\nu:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\chi_{M_{n}}\,{\rm d}\mu
$$
is finite ($\nu$ has density $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\chi_{M_{n}}$
with respect to $\mu$, where $\chi_{M_{n}}$ is the indicator function
of $M_{n}$).

Note that the "difference measure" $\lambda = \mu - \nu$ is given by
$$
d\lambda=\left(1-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\chi_{M_{n}}\right)\, d\mu.
$$
In particular, any function $h$ supported on the set $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}M_{n}$
will have $\int h\, d\lambda=0$ (and the integral converges absolutely).

All that remains is to choose $h$ in such a way that $\int h\,{\rm d}\mu=\infty$
and $\int h\,{\rm d}\nu=\infty$. The second identity is automatic
if $\int h\,{\rm d}\mu=\infty$ (why? use that $h$ is supported in
$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}M_{n}$).

Now a valid choice will be
$$
h=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{n}\chi_{M_{n}},
$$
since we have
$$
\int h\,{\rm d}\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{n}\mu\left(M_{n}\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}1=\infty.
$$
BTW: Good catch in noting the incompleteness of the proof!

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: @PhoemueX I didn't get that at all at first. I think there are a few typos. Surely you meant you want $\int h\,d\nu=\infty$, not $-\infty$? And surely you meant $h=\sum 2^n\chi_{M_n}$, not $2^{-n}$? That last one makes me wonder, because I see the $2^{-n}$ in two places. But $\sum2^{-n}2^{-n}$ is finite...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, the part about the definition of $h$ is correct, I will fix it. You are also right about the $\nu$ integral. Somehow, I thought we would have $\lambda = \mu + \nu$ with $\nu$ a negative measure. WIll also edit that.

Comment: @PhoemueX Look again. The two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the same on the support of $h$, so the integrals must be the same. Or to put it another way: With your example the original equality becomes $0=\infty-(-\infty)$. You're not going to get an example that violates things that way! You can get an example where the original equality reads $0=\infty-\infty$. (As you do once you fix the signs in your example).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, I noted that right after I posted my first comment (which I then edited). Now everything should be alright (?!)

Comment: @PhoemueX I see you caught one minus sign that I didn't mention, so I imagine you got them all...

Answer (score 6):

Simpler example: $X=[0,1]$, $\mu=\nu=$ Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, $f(t)=1/t$. Then $\lambda=0$ so the left side exists, but the right side is $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. +1

Comment: Oh yes, it could have been so easy :)