# If the right side of $\int f\ d\lambda = \int f\ d\mu − \int f\ d\nu$ exists, does the left one exist as well?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two positive measures, at least one of which is finite, on a measurable space $(X, \mathfrak{A})$. Let $\lambda$ be a signed measure on $(X, \mathfrak{A})$ defined by setting $\lambda = \mu - \nu$. Let $f$ be an extended real-valued $\mathfrak{A}$-measurable function on $X$.

Consider the following equality, which is known to hold whenever both sides of the equation exist (which happens, in particular, when $f$ is bounded).
$$
\int_X f\ d\lambda = \int_X f\ d\mu - \int_X f\ d\nu \tag{*}
$$
The integral on the left is by definition $\int_X f\ d\lambda^+ - \int_X f\ d\lambda^-$, where $\lambda = \lambda^+ - \lambda^-$ is the unique Jordan decomposition of $\lambda$.

[It can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348889/if-one-side-of-int-f-d-lambda-int-f-d-mu-int-f-d-nu-exists-does-the) that it is possible for the left side of the equation to exist (and be finite) while the right side is undefined (i.e. the right side is of the form $\infty - \infty$).

What about the converse? Is it possible for the right side to exist in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ while the left side is undefined? Is it possible for the right side to exist in $\mathbb{R}$ while the left side is undefined?